# Restringir versões iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, apple

Há alguma maneira de eu restringir versões do iOS?

**Detalhe: Não é a versão minima**

Por exemplo, eu desenvolvi um aplicativo e gostaria que ele rodasse nas versões iOS 7.x.x e iOS 8.1.x. Resumindo, gostaria de evitar que o aplicativo fosse instalado nas versões iOS 8.0.x.

Por que? Atualmente no iOS 7 funciona perfeitamente, no iOS 8.1.x também, porém no iOS 8.0.x o aplicativo apresenta vários problemas, inclusive crashes constantes.

Comment: Sugiro que você verifique e repare os erros. Se você impedir que o app rode na versão 8.0 existe uma grande chance da Apple rejeitá-lo caso o reviewer faça algum teste no 8.0.

Comment: Então @AndréRibeiro, isso é tenso, nas simulações que foram feitas e testes aqui, está tudo OK, porém tem usuário relatando problemas, o qual a versão do iOS é a 8.0. Em um iPhone 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impedir a instalação não é possível, mas no `AppDelegate` você pode verificar a versão do dispositivo e impedir que ele conclua a abertura de acordo com a versão do sistema operacional.

```
var systemVersion = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion();
```

Mas sendo franco, além de não conseguir aprovação da **Apple** para publicação, naturalmente porque você vai ter que "matar" (com um `abort()`) o aplicativo antes de concluir a abertura, isso é um *workaround* muito ruim em qualquer caso e em qualquer área de desenvolvimento (*me lembra muito quando eu não queria que meus sites rodassem no Internet Explorer*).

Meu conselho é: não adianta tapar o sol com a peneira. O ideal é você permanecer com a versão mínima e tentar localizar quais as falhas ocorrem com o seu aplicativo no ambiente com iOS 8.0 para poder solucioná-las de forma que isso não seja impedimento.

Se você acatar essa ideia, vai fazendo suas perguntar, pesquisando e etc, porque problema em uma versão específica do sistema operacional é mais cara de incompatibilidade de um certo código, o que é totalmente apto para ser resolvido.

Comment: Obrigado Paulo, pois é cara, o problema que mais comum acontece é que o Core Location simplesmente se perde. Não encontra mais localização, tendo que reiniciar serviço de localização e dependendo do caso, em um iPad wifi por exemplo, tenho de reiniciar serviço de internet.

Comment: O problema é que nos testes, os mesmos apresentaram sucesso, tudo ok. Bem no fim, após o lançamento ele está ocorrendo, e em um iPhone 5 iOS 8.0. Pesquisando e tudo mais os erros de localização (Que não é aquele esquema de requisitar a permissão, pois isso está OK), o pessoal não obtiveram solução, pois parece ser algo de gerenciamento interno do iOS ou do dispositivo em questão

Comment: Basicamente o erro que está acontecendo é este: didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

Comment: @Gian Dê uma olhada nesta resposta: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6768989)

Comment: @Paulo Rodrigues, exato foi através deste link que encontrei a conclusão de que realmente é algum gerenciamento "fora" do alcance do código do meu aplicativo, pois até mesmo o Google Maps, que utilizo em meu app, acaba se perdendo na localização do dispositivo.

Comment: Eu já me deparei com esse problema, mas sempre foi no simulador (inclusive em outras versões do iOS), assim como neste link que o *André* passou e outros que também encontrei. E tendo relação com a conexão, acredito que seja preciso fazer mais testes em outros dispositivos com iOS 8.0, pois pode ser questão específica de aparelho, seja software ou hardware.